# Git tagging working in command line but not elsewhere

Tags: git, tags

I'm successfully tagging my git releases in the command line:

```
~/u/git/Render $ git tag
20190805-1530z
20190809-0100z
20190812-0140z
20190825-2320z
20190827-2310z
20190914-0200z
20190915-0120z
20190916-1940z
20190917-1210z
20190918-1220z
20190919-0020z
~/u/git/Render $
```

But both the OSX app and the web interface report there are no tags associated with the repository:

> There aren’t any releases here
>
> Releases are powered by tagging specific points of history in a repository. They’re great for marking release points like v1.0.

What might I be doing wrong? Is it absolutely required that the format be "v#.#.#"? In our international project we don't work that way, rather, we work on Zulu time.

Thank you for any guidance!

. . . . . . Ken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly enough, tags are not automatically pushed. You can use the following command to push only tags that are reachable and annotated.

```
git push --follow-tags
```

This will make your tags available in the other repositories.

You can also use the following to push all tags in your repository.

```
git push --tags
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, very kindly. All my tags are now visible as "releases".